# SQL how to split one row to multiple between two time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a row like:

```
EMPID   INTIME  OUTTIME JOBCODE
1       4:00     5:00    ABC
2       5:00     8:00    ABC
```

Expected Output:

```
EMPID   TIMEID  JOBCODE     MINUTE
1       16          ABC     15
1       17          ABC     15
1       18          ABC     15
1       19          ABC     15
```

TIMEID FOR  4:00 is 16 and increase with 15 minutes threshold.

I have tried with below query but it generates a single row.

```
SELECT
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(INTIME,'HH24:MI:SS'),0,2)* 4) + ROUND(TO_NUMBER((SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(INTIME,'HH24:MI:SS'),4,2)))/15,0) AS TIMEID,
EMPID,
JOBCODE,
 MINUTE FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: You need to mention also how have you tried?

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you expect the minutes to work. You say the minutes will increase with 15 minutes increments, but you sample does not show that

Comment: timeid will increase after every 15 minute, not minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split 1 row like that as below:

```
with 
x as 
(select 1 Empid, to_date('01-JAN-1900 '||'4:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') intime, to_date('01-JAN-1900 '||'5:12','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') outtime from dual)
Select Empid,intime,(newtime-nvl(lag(newtime) over (order by newtime),intime))*1440 Required_Intervals,outtime,newtime
from (
select EmpId,InTime,Case When Outtime > INTIME+(15*rownum/1440) Then INTIME+(15*rownum/1440) Else Outtime End newTime,OUTTIME
from x
connect by rownum <= CEIL(((outtime-intime)*1440)/15))
```

> 1440 = 24 (hours per day) * 60 (minutes per hour) = total minutes per day

Please note it will work for only 1 row. For multiple rows as well you can create a query using multiset & connect by level if required.

The query also accounts for when the out-time is not in intervals of 15.

Comment: your solution is working for 1 row only as you also mentioned. Can you please help me out to make this work-full for multi rows. I have tried several scenario with connect by but no success.

Comment: post Updated with example of two rows.